# Finding a path to X in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, path

Given a n x n matrix as an input We have to find if a path of 1s exist from (0,0) to X(mid of matrix).e.g input is

```
1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 X 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

The output should be true as we have this path

```
1
1
1   X 1 1
1       1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Can someone please explain a better way to do this.Thanks.Here's my algorithm:

Input Matrix is A where X is represented by any positive number
Visited matrix[n][n] is initialised to zeros
intially flag=0;
call is made to find(0,0,&flag) and then we check for flag=1 for presence of a path.

```
void find(int i,int j,int * flag)
{

    visited[i][j]=1;

    if(i==n/2)and(j==n/2)
    {
    *flag=1;
     return
    }

    if(A[i+1][j]>0)and(visited[i+1]==0)and(i+1<n)
    find(i+1,j,flag);

    if(A[i-1][j]>0)and(visited[i-1]==0)and(i-1>0)
    find(i-1,j,flag);

    if(A[i][j+1]>0)and(visited[j+1]==0)and(j+1<n)
    find(i,j+1,flag);

    if(A[i][j-1]>0)and(visited[j-1]==0)and(j-1>0)
    find(i,j-1,flag);
}
```

Comment: What make you say it's exponential?  Post code please.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive algorithm is probably a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), that does not maintain a `visited` set, and thus re-expand nodes multiple times.

It can be solved by adding and maintaining a `visited` set, that if a certain node is in the set, you skip it and do not re-expand it.

A better alternative is using [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) rather than a DFS. BFS also maintain a `visited` set (or `parent` set if you want to find the path too later on) by default, and also guarantees the shortest path from source to target is found.

Pesudo code for BFS:

```
q = new empty queue
parent = {} //new empty dictionary
q.enqueue((0,0))
parent[(0,0)] = null
while q is not empty:
    current = q.dequeue()
    if current is the target x:
         return findPath(parent, current)
    for each neighbor n of current:
       if n is a key in parent:
          continue
       q.add(n)
       parent[n] = current

findPath(parent, target):
    l = new list
    while (target != null):
       l.add(target)
       target = parent[target]
```